# "Queue empty" Exception

Tags: c#, sendkeys, keyboard-hook

When I use `SendKeys.SendWait` I got some times "Queue empty" exception, here is its trace

```
   at System.Collections.Queue.Dequeue()
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendInput(Byte[] oldKeyboardState, Queue    previousEvents)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(String keys, Control control, Boolean wait)
   at System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(String keys)
   at WindowsFormsApplication2.InterceptKeys.HookCallback(Int32 nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) in e:\Programing\C#\TypeHebrew\WindowsFormsApplication2\InterceptKeys.cs:line 69
```

and here is my procesure

```
 private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

                if (vkCode == 160 || vkCode == 161) { shift = 1; }
                if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163) { ctrl = 1; }
                if (vkCode == 164 || vkCode == 165) { alt = 1; }
                Console.WriteLine(vkCode + "_" + shift);
                int res = replaceKey.getReplacedKey(vkCode, shift);
                if (res != -1 && ctrl == 0 && alt == 0 && getCurrentKeyboardLangauge().Contains("Hebrew"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SendKeys.SendWait(char.ConvertFromUtf32((int)res));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Debug.Print(ex.Message);
                    }
                    return (System.IntPtr)1;
                }else if(getCurrentKeyboardLangauge().Contains("Hebrew") && (vkCode == 79 || vkCode == 89 ||  vkCode == 69 ||  vkCode == 81 ||  vkCode == 220 ||  vkCode == 77 ||  vkCode == 78 ||  vkCode == 66 ||  vkCode == 76 ||  vkCode == 88 ||  vkCode == 90 ||  vkCode == 226)){
                    return (System.IntPtr)1;
                }
            }
            else if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                //Console.WriteLine(vkCode);
                if (vkCode == 160 || vkCode == 161) { shift = 0; }
                if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163) { ctrl = 0; }
                if (vkCode == 164 || vkCode == 165) { alt = 0; }                
            }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Any Help

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occurs because the key sent is "re-hooked" and so sent and rehook again and again ...

To avoid this in a similar situation, I had to set a temp boolean to know if the key is a real key stroke sent by the user or the key my program just sent via the SendKeys method.

Try something like this :

```
 private static bool _intercept = true;

 private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
 {
      if (_intercept)
      {
           if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
           {
               int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

               if (vkCode == 160 || vkCode == 161) { shift = 1; }
               if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163) { ctrl = 1; }
               if (vkCode == 164 || vkCode == 165) { alt = 1; }
               Console.WriteLine(vkCode + "_" + shift);
               int res = replaceKey.getReplacedKey(vkCode, shift);
               if (res != -1 && ctrl == 0 && alt == 0 && getCurrentKeyboardLangauge().Contains("Hebrew"))
               {
                   try
                   {
                       _intercept = false; // Stop listening keystroke for the next key
                       SendKeys.SendWait(char.ConvertFromUtf32((int)res));
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Debug.Print(ex.Message);
                   }
                   finally
                   {
                       _intercept = true; // Reactivate listening keystroke for the next key
                   }
                   return (System.IntPtr)1;
               }
               else if (getCurrentKeyboardLangauge().Contains("Hebrew") && (vkCode == 79 || vkCode == 89 || vkCode == 69 || vkCode == 81 || vkCode == 220 || vkCode == 77 || vkCode == 78 || vkCode == 66 || vkCode == 76 || vkCode == 88 || vkCode == 90 || vkCode == 226))
               {
                   return (System.IntPtr)1;
               }
           }
           else if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYUP)
           {
               int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
               //Console.WriteLine(vkCode);
               if (vkCode == 160 || vkCode == 161) { shift = 0; }
               if (vkCode == 162 || vkCode == 163) { ctrl = 0; }
               if (vkCode == 164 || vkCode == 165) { alt = 0; }
           }
       }
       return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   }
```

You can see a similar approach in the AutoTyper application here : https://github.com/nmariot/AutoTyper