# Getting an "Empty Queue" exception in C#

Tags: c#, exception, queue

I am trying to run multiple requests at the same time with a proxy. I want a proxy to initiate one request at a time, that's why I have a `gethandlerindexed` function

Also, the error occurs during the last call to `gethandlerindexed`, here max = 2, so I have 2 proxies, 2 user agents but it doesn't work. The error in question is: Empty queue

I do not understand where this error can come from.

```
int indext = 0;

private async Task DoDownload(IEnumerable<ClearanceHandler> handlers, SemaphoreSlim sem, string url)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);

    try
    {
        await sem.WaitAsync();
        indext++;
        var client = new HttpClient(gethandlerindexed(indext, handlers)); // error in question appear here
        string link_image = null;

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                link_image = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                richTextBox1.TextInvoke(link_image);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        sem.Release();
    }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 20;
}

ClearanceHandler gethandlerindexed(int nb, IEnumerable<ClearanceHandler> handlers)
{
    return (handlers.ElementAt(nb % handlers.Count()));
}

Queue<string> getdatafromfile(string path)
{
    Queue<string> q = new Queue<string>();

    var proxies = File.ReadAllLines(path);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        q.Enqueue(proxies[i]);

    return (q);
}

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var proxies = getdatafromfile(PATH + "\\proxy\\proxy.txt");
    var useragents = getdatafromfile(PATH + "\\proxy\\user-agents.txt");

    // MessageBox.Show(proxies.Count() + " / " + useragents.Count());

    var max = proxies.Count();
    var handlers = Enumerable.Range(0, max).Select(_ => new ClearanceHandler(proxies.Dequeue()) { UserAgent = useragents.Dequeue(), MaxTimeout = 6000 });
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(max, max);

    await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var downloads = Enumerable.Range(0, max).Select((_ => "http://google.com")).ToArray();
            var tasks = downloads.Select(dl => DoDownload(handlers, semaphore, dl));
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        });
}
```

[Error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGQaU.png)

Comment: Please paste the full error.  Could this be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210799/queue-empty-exception

Comment: Try checking that there is something in the queue before you call Dequeue.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, max).Select((_ => "http://google.com")).ToArray();` would be _much_ simpler using `Enumerable.Repeat`.

Comment: `await Task.Run(async () =>` I suspect that line of code is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you're repeatedly draining your queues.

You start off creating two queues:

```
var proxies = getdatafromfile(PATH + "\\proxy\\proxy.txt");
var useragents = getdatafromfile(PATH + "\\proxy\\user-agents.txt");
```

You create `IEnumerable<ClearanceHandler> handlers` like this:

```
var handlers = Enumerable.Range(0, max).Select(_ => new ClearanceHandler(proxies.Dequeue()) { UserAgent = useragents.Dequeue(), MaxTimeout = 6000 });
```

You pass that to `DoDownload` and it calls this:

```
var client = new HttpClient(gethandlerindexed(indext, handlers));
```

That in term calls `handlers.ElementAt(nb % handlers.Count())` in `gethandlerindexed`.

Now, because `handlers` is an `IEnumerable<ClearanceHandler>` you are rerunning the enumerable each time. So it keeps calling `proxies.Dequeue()` and `useragents.Dequeue()` each time it runs.

Here's what should work for you:

```
var handlers =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, max)
        .Select(_ => new ClearanceHandler(proxies.Dequeue()) { UserAgent = useragents.Dequeue(), MaxTimeout = 6000 })
        .ToArray();
```

Note the `.ToArray()`. That forces a single execution of the enumerable. As long as both queues have the same number of elements it should work fine.

Comment: It seems working fine ! thank you a lot ;)